# Input type: Reverse polish notation evaluation C++

Tags: c++, stack, calculator, postfix-notation

I'm trying to code a calculator which evaluates a entered postfix expression.

Currently im trying to get the input with a character array, which isn't working out too well. Maybe you have suggestions for a better input construct. Or maybe you cant spot any other mistakes, because I'm getting the wrong results...

As you can propably see i'm fairly new to C++.

The code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stack>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


int performOperation(int operand1, int operand2, char op)
{
    int ans;
    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        ans = operand2 + operand1;
        break;
    case '-':
        ans = operand2 - operand1;
        break;
    case '*':
        ans = operand2 * operand1;
        break;
    case '/':
        ans = operand2 / operand1;
        break;
    }
    return ans;
}


bool checkOperator(char character)
{
    if (character == '+' || character == '-' || character == '*' || character == '/')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int solvePostfix(char postfix[], int size) {
    stack<int> s; 
    int i = 0;
    char character;
    int value;
    value = 0;

    while (i < size) 
    {
        character = postfix[i];
        if (isdigit(character))  //ist Operand, pushe ihn auf Stack s
        {   
            s.push(character);
        }else if (checkOperator(postfix[i]))        //ist Operator, nehme die zwei Operanden vom Stack und benutze den Operator
           {                        
            int operand1 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            int operand2 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            value = performOperation(operand1, operand2, character);
            s.push(value);      //pushe den Ergebniswert auf Stack
            }
        i++;
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    char exp[100];

    cout << "Bitte Postfix eingeben: " << endl;
    cin >> exp;
    int size = sizeof(exp);

    int val = solvePostfix(exp, size);
    cout << "\nErgebnis ist: " << val << endl;
}
```

Comment: i know that 'sizeof(exp)' always returns '100' here

Comment: "I'm getting errors", could you please be more specific:  compimlation errors ?  runtime errors ?  discrepancy between resutls and expectations ?

Comment: That's probably because `sizeof(exp)` **IS** 100. If you want the length of the null-terminated string of characters stored in `exp`, then you can use `strlen(exp)`... BTW, since you're working with C++, why not just use a C++ string (`std::string`) instead of a C-string (an array of `char`s ending with `\0`)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm gettin a Runtime Error: "Debug Assertion failed!"

Comment: @barak manos Ok, changed sizeof(exp) to strlen(exp) no more Runtime errors, but wrong result...

Comment: instead of `s.push(character);` you should use `s.push(character - '0');` to translate an ASCII character into an `int`.

Comment: @Franck thanks alot, that was missing. =) Any idea how to implement the space between the numbers? e.g. 3 2 + instead of 32+

Comment: @user343037 you can use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char[100]` and fill it while `cin.good()` (end with Ctrl+D) or other condition. `cin >> s` stops on whitespace character when `s` is a string.